# Django model objects AJAX GET not getting response

Tags: django, ajax, django-models, get

I'm trying to get model objects (municipality) that have the same foreign object key (governorate ) on user click. but I'm getting no response, when I append url I get a 404 No Governorate matches the given query...

**Here are the models in question:**

```
class Governorate(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Municipality(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mun_d=models.TextField()
    gov=models.ForeignKey(Governorate, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('forums-home', kwargs={'municipality': self.name})
```

**Django view**

```
def municipality_by_gov(request):

    if request.is_ajax and request.method == 'GET':
        gov_name = request.GET.get('gov_name', False)
        gov = get_object_or_404(Governorate, name=gov_name)
        gov_muns = Municipality.objects.filter(gov=gov)


        data = serializers.serialize('json', gov_muns)

        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

**Django URL**

```
path('ajax/MunByGov/', municipality_by_gov, name='MunByGov'),
```

**Script**

```
$('.GovLink').click(function(){
        $('#GovModalLabel').text($(this).data('name'));
        var gov_name=$(this).data('name');           
        $.ajax( 
        { 
            type:"GET", 
            url: "{% url 'MunByGov' %}", 
            datatype: 'json',
            data:{ gov_name: gov_name }, 
        success: function( response ) 
        { 
            var response = JSON.parse(response)[0];

            document.getElementById("text-container").innerHTML = response.fields.name;

            },


                      }) });
```

Comment: `{gov_name: gov_name}` has the wrong key. Look at the request that your browser sent in the network tab of your browser debug tools or in your django runserver console. You’re not sending the query parameter `'gov_name'`

Comment: Thank you @dirkgroten
The problem was: I was using the slim build of jQuery, which had some things removed, ajax being one of them. 

The solution: Just download the regular (compressed or not) version of jQuery  and include it in your project.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem you showed in your question. If you cannot reproduce just close your question. But the issue you describe cannot be due to ajax not working since you were getting a request.

Comment: I was getting the request when I append the view link to url bar but not as ajax. I still think this is important for future, who, like me, might be asking the same "wrong question".

Comment: Maybe but I doubt this is useful, since doing $.ajax would give you an error in the console if $.ajax is not defined. Still, in your question, the `data` is wrong, so it cannot work, because you're not sending a request with query parameter "gov_name". The final requested url should look like /ajax/MunByGov/?gov_name=something which is not the case now (it's /ajax/NumByGov/?something=something)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was: I was using the slim build of jQuery, which had some things removed, ajax being one of them. The solution: Just download the regular (compressed or not) version of jQuery and include it in your project.

That is to say use  instead of

Appearently this is a common trap, I hope this helps someone else.